# Convergence almost surely and in $\mathcal{L}^1$ for square of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ almost surely, then is $Y_n^2 \rightarrow Y^2$ almost surely too?

If $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, then is $Y_n^2 \rightarrow Y^2$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$ too?

I am struggling with trying to decide if the statements are true or false. My guess for the almost sure part is that it is true because I can't seem to find a counterexample. Would appreciate any advice on this or hints on how to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is true, in fact if $(X_n) \rightarrow X$ almost surely then $(f(X_n)) \rightarrow f(X)$ almost surely for any continuous function $f$.  You can prove this the same way you prove it for a sequence of real numbers.

The second one is false.  We can have a random variable $Y \in L^1$ that is not square integrable, so $Y^2 \not \in L^1$ and hence can't be the $L^1$ limit of any sequence of random variables.  For example, considering the probability space $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure, we could have $f(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not immediately think of continuous functions but that does make a lot of sense now.